# Changing many filenames using slightly differing prefixes

Tags: python

I'm trying to change a lot of file names at once but have run into a problem I can not figure out. I have a list of filenames that all start with "#### - " 
i.e. "1942 - testfile001.txt"

all files start with a "yyyy - " a four digit year, a space, a dash, and a space ...
I want to remove all of this "yyyy - " and keep the rest
[image: image of dir listing of files]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from os import rename, listdir

badprefix = "1942 - "
fnames = listdir('H:/testing/1928-1949/')

for fname in fnames:
    if fname.startswith(badprefix):
        rename(fname, fname.replace(badprefix, '', 1))
```

When I use the specific text above, badprefix = "1942 - ", it works for only files that of course start with 1942

any time I try to throw in a wildcard (#,*,?), badprefix = "19## - " or badprefix = "19?? - " it doesn't work.

My questions are:

1. In the *badprefix* variable, what would I use so that any and all files that start with "#### - " are included?
2. What should I be reading to understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean *"doesn't work"*, exactly? What debugging have you done? Give a [mcve].

Comment: by doesn't work I mean it doesnt change the file names i.e:

badprefix = "???? - "
badprefix = "#### - "
badprefix = "* - "

Comment: Why would it? You don't seem to have any code related to the wildcards you're describing.

Comment: had a look at `pathlib` or `glob`?

Comment: As I said, I'm a total noob I don't understand what you are stating here, and I'm out tof time to find the answer myself

Comment: @MrFuppes only saw them in passing while trying to find the answer

Comment: That's unfortunate, but your deadline doesn't alter the rules: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Comment: I think @jonrsharpe has a point. [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/11301900 ) meta post may be of use. I’m confused by your use of the term _wildcard_, can you expand on that a bit?

Comment: A wildcard like * in windows
as in: *.zip meaning anything that ends with .zip

again I am a noob asking the question is as tough as figuring the problem itself, I am sorry if I am breaking rules

Comment: the question could benefit from a clarification what is meant by "slightly differing prefixes". e.g. something like '1942 - ' vs. '1942-' in the specific case. also, [wildcard character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character) seems to need clarification. in the end, you want to do a search like 'xxxx*' meaning anything starting with 'xxxx' followed by zero or more other random characters?

Comment: yea all files start with a "yyyy - " a four digit year, a space a dash, and a space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this code solve your problem?

```
import os, glob
path = "/tmp/test/"
files = "*.txt"
dummy_year = "1234 - "

for oldpath in glob.glob(path + files):
    newpath = path + oldpath[len(path)+len(dummy_year):]
    print("from: ", oldpath, "to:", newpath)
    os.rename(oldpath, newpath)
```

It renames

```
1234 - cdef abc sdf.txt
1946 - abcde sdf.txt
```

to

```
abcde sdf.txt
cdef abc sdf.txt
```

Comment: Yes if that works as advertised, then that will do what I want exactly

Comment: Yes it worked... I did get an error at the end but it did complete and finish all that I needed, thank you...

edit, the error was a random file that shouldn't have been there and not an issue at all with the solution you provided

Comment: @FedaykinWolf: this just removes 7 characters (regardless what they are!) from all filenames in the directory that have the '.txt' ending.

Comment: you could do that in one (arguably too long) line: `_ = [os.rename(os.path.join(p, f), os.path.join(p, f[7:])) for f in os.listdir(p) if f.endswith('.txt')]`

Comment: I figured that out - the any 7 characters, but it worked for what I needed... Thank you for adding more information, this is wonderful... now at least i can research my way to the next problem i can not solve myself... which won't be long ;)